# retrieving a column value from a selected row sql php

Tags: php, sql

Hi thank you for reading!

I have a checkbox form that takes all the data from a database.

there are 3 columns in the form: id, link, action('submit' button)

when a user clicks the 'submit' button under column 'action', the browser will load the corresponding link in the same row.

i've been working this for a while, couldn't find anything on Google. 
so now i only have something like this: when the user clicks any button, the browser generates all the links appeard in the form instead of the just generating the one i clicked.

If you guys could help, it'd be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Put a `<form>`/`</form>` in each row, not one for the whole table, if you only want that row's values to be submitted. Make sure there is an input (hidden or otherwise) in that form that somehow identifies which row is being submitted.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. I tried that but it still does the same thing. each button should already be associated with the row.

<input name="reboardcast" type="submit" id="reboardcast" value="Re-Broadcast">

should i change the value to 'link' or something?

Comment: Is "reboardcast" (sic, your spelling error) the name of whatever's in this row? And you're checking for every single key in your PHP code, like `isset($_POST['reboardcast'])`? That sounds overly complicated. Why not something like `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="rebroadcast">`, in separate `<form>` tags, and you check the value of `$_POST['id']` to know which one was submitted.

Comment: sorry im very slow at this. i am working on it now. Thank you!

Comment: i hope im heading to the right direction. so right now i have another question, how to take the corresponding column data from the $_POST['id']?